# How do I add text to the location of a user's cursor in a Rich Text Box in C#?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

In Visual C#.NET:

How do I add/append text directly to where the user's cursor is in a Rich Text Box?

For example, if the user clicked a button, and their cursor was somewhere in the rich text box, text would be immediately added to the location of their cursor.

Answer (score 19):

Use the [`SelectedText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedtext.aspx) property:

```
textBox.SelectedText = "New text";
```

This will overwrite any selected text they have though. If you don't want that you can first set the [`SelectionLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionlength.aspx) property to 0:

```
textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
textBox.SelectedText = "New text";
```

Answer (score 9):

```
     rtb.SelectionStart += rtb.SelectionLength;
     rtb.SelectionLength = 0;
     rtb.SelectedText = "asdf";
```

This moves the cursor just past the end of the current selection, then adds "asdf" at the end.